# Can someone help me my minecraft crashes every time i press play from the lancher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have minecraft and I have just deleted a resource pack called "SugerPack", which was for 1.10. I briefly had the Orespawn mod installed, but I have uninstalled it since then. When I upgraded to minecraft 1.11 my minecraft just crashes every time I open it now. I also went to the options document and deleted "SugerPack" there also but still it does not work :( Here is my crash log.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Don't be sad, have a hug! <3

Time: 5/12/16 7:43 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:598)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434)
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:598)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.10.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 54624112 bytes (52 MB) / 152051712 bytes (145 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.10.2
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs:
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Comment: Do you have an nVidea graphics card?

Comment: Probably something to do with windows 10

Comment: Oddly, this isn't even attempting to run 1.11.

Comment: Sorry about approving edit 3, I misread the markdown and thought it was *adding* the code formatting.

Comment: where would i find the error codes? Would they be in the "options"?

Comment: what do I need to do to fix it? upgrade to windows 10? I can't free up any space because Minecraft is the app that is taking up all of the data.

Comment: Will B. What is duplicated?

Answer (score -1):

This is not tested but:

Try:

-Downgrade java to java 8u51

or

-Update java to newest or recommended version.

-Update Drivers

There is a chance that your computer does not have a good enough graphic card. Also if you have a resource pack alerady installed, try to remove it from your resource pack folder.